# Input element not finding its value

Tags: javascript, html

```
function makeUL() {

var products = JSON.parse(localStorage["products"]);

var list = document.createElement('ul');

for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if(products[i].amount == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    // Create the list item:
    var item = document.createElement('li');

    var product = products[i];

    var totalPrice = product.amount * product.price;
    var toDisplay = product.name + " " + product.amount + " @" + totalPrice + " ";

    // Set its contents:
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(toDisplay));
    var inputbox = document.createElement("input");
    inputbox.setAttribute("id", "inputboxProduct" + i);
    inputbox.addEventListener("change", function(){
        changeAmountProd(inputbox.id);
    });
    item.appendChild(inputbox);

    // Add it to the list:
    list.appendChild(item);
}

// Finally, return the constructed list:
return list;
}
```

This will basically make a list when you hover over a certain string. The list will be based on the localstorage and make an inputbox for each point of that list.
The problem is the adding of eventlisteners. For some reason it always returns an empty value when the event is triggered of that inputbox.

```
function changeAmountProd(inputboxId) {
var products = JSON.parse(localStorage["products"]);

value = document.getElementById(inputboxId).value;

if(value < 1) {
    return;
}
products[i].amount = value;

localStorage["products"] = JSON.stringify(products);

makeUL();
}
```

Comment: If you could provide a JSFiddle for this, it would be much easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the callback of your `change` event. You're referring to the changed element using the `inputbox` variable (that is available through the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)) but by the time your callback is invoked, `inputbox` will always point to the last generated element.

Try this instead:

```
inputbox.addEventListener("change", function(){
    changeAmountProd(this.id);
});
```

See [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function makeUL() {

    var products = JSON.parse(localStorage["products"]);

    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if(products[i].amount == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        var product = products[i];

        var totalPrice = product.amount * product.price;
        var toDisplay = product.name + " " + product.amount + " @" + totalPrice + " ";

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(toDisplay));
        var inputbox = document.createElement("input");
        inputbox.setAttribute("id", "inputboxProduct" + i);
        inputbox.addEventListener("change", function(){
            changeAmountProd(this.id);
        });
        item.appendChild(inputbox);

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

// Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Yea, I see my error. Thanks a lot! Ill accept when I'm allowed to accept your answer :)

Comment: You should accept @haim770 answer - he wrote an explanation. I've just posted code snippet faster then him :)